# Change color of indices and elements of an array?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I would like to highlight elements of an array swapping. Right now I have this

[image]

but I'd like to know three things. Firstly, how to color certain indices of this array. Second, how to color certain elements of the array. Third, how to color certain indices and its corresponding element of the array.

Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{index}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{index}{0}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {3, 1, 4, 1, 5}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \node at ($(s)-(0,0.5)$) {\theindex};
      \stepcounter{index}
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:testArray}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you have only five elements just go `\foreach\x/\xc/\xb in {3/red/yellow,1/blue/green...}` Then use those colors in box colors and text colors. Don't use the macro name `\num` it is used elsewhere

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work. Can you clarify what to do with my macro num since it is used for the nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the array like

```
\acunaarray{3,1,[red]4,*[blue]1,5}
```

where `[red]4` will only make the cell's contents red; adding a `*`, also the index will be colored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\arrayelement}{sou\q_stop}
 {
  \node[minimum~size=6mm, draw, rectangle]~at~(s)~
    { \IfValueT{#2}{\color{#2}} #3 };
  \node at~($(s)-(0,0.5)$)~
    { \IfBooleanT{#1}{\color{#2}}\int_to_arabic:n { \l_acuna_index_int } };
  \int_incr:N \l_acuna_index_int
  \coordinate (s)~at~($(s) + (1,0)$);
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\acunaarray}{m}
 {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \int_zero:N \l_acuna_index_int
  \coordinate (s)~at~(0,0);
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \arrayelement##1\q_stop
   }
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
\int_new:N \l_acuna_index_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\acunaarray{3,1,[red]4,*[blue]1,5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

\num is a pretty often used macro in TeX packages. Try to avoid using straight words for macro names or prefix them with `my` such `\mynum`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x\xc\xb[count=\xi from 0] in {3/red/blue, 1/red/blue, 4/blue/red, 1/yellow/black, 5/blue/green}{
    \node[draw=\xc,text=\xb,label=-90:\xi] (s-\xi) at (\xi,0) {\x}; 
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\foreach[count=\i]` to have an extra variable that represents the current index in the loop. To iterate over pairs of values (in this case an index and a color) you can say `\foreach \n/\thecolor in {1/red,2/black}{do stuff}`. If you don't provide a second element of the pair like `{1/red,2}` then the second variable will default to the same value as the first, so you can test whether the two variables are equal and provide a default. To do this check, I say `\ifx\n\thecolor \def\thecolor{black} \fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle}]
    \foreach[count=\i] \n/\thecolor in {3, 1/red, 4/red, 1, 5}{
        \ifx\n\thecolor \def\thecolor{black}\fi % make color default to black
        \draw (\i,0) 
           node[cell,text=\thecolor] {\n} 
           node[below=0.5cm] {\i};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[count=\i] \n/\thecolor in {3, 1/red, 4/red, 1, 5}{
      \ifx\n\thecolor \def\thecolor{black}\fi 
       \draw (\i,0) 
           node[cell] {\n} 
           node[below=0.5cm,text=\thecolor] {\i};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```